# Outlook 2010 Rule for Messages To/From *@company.com

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

Is it possible to set up a rule to copy all e-mails sent to or from a particular domain into a folder? The conversation view does not seem to pick up some sent items when I simply do this for items received from the domain (however, it does so when I do a manual conversation search)

I could do a search for `from:company.com OR to:company.com`, but I'd much prefer to have a folder for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure. Just create a rule and specify "with specific words in the sender's address" or "with specific words in the recipient's address" condition. Add @company.com to the word list and specify the "move it to the specified folder" action as required.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find a way to make the condition an "or", so I created 2 sets of rules instead.